# Malformed content exception while trying to get the signature from a certificate

Tags: java, security, certificate, bouncycastle, sign

I have written the below code to verify the signature of a file using a certificate that is there in my certificate store. But when I try to get its signature and pass it to the SignedData method, I am getting the below exception.

```
org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: Malformed content.
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSUtils.readContentInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSUtils.readContentInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at VerifyFinal.main(VerifyFinal.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERApplicationSpecific
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.ContentInfo.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

Below is the code I used to verify the signature of the file.

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

            KeyStore msCertStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
            msCertStore.load(null, null);
            X509Certificate cer = ((X509Certificate) msCertStore.getCertificate("Software View Certificate Authority"));
            PublicKey pubKey = cer.getPublicKey();

            byte[] sigToVerify = cer.getSignature();
            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA", "BC");
            signature.initVerify(pubKey);

            CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(cer.getSignature());
            Store store = cms.getCertificates();
            SignerInformationStore signers = cms.getSignerInfos();
            Collection c = signers.getSigners();
            Iterator it = c.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next();
                Collection certCollection = store.getMatches(signer.getSID());
                Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
                X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
                X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certHolder);
                if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert))) {
                    System.out.println("verified");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In case you need, below is how I signed the file.

```
 File file = new File("G:\\Projects\\test.zip");
        fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];


        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_INSTANCE);
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());
        Key key = ks.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());

        //Sign
        PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey) key;
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA", "BC");
        signature.initSign(privKey);
        signature.update(fileContent);

        //Build CMS
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(KEYSTORE_ALIAS);
        List certList = new ArrayList();
        CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signature.sign());
        certList.add(cert);
        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(privKey);
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()).build(sha1Signer, cert));
        gen.addCertificates(certs);
        CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, true);

        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();

        String signedContent = encoder.encode((byte[]) sigData.getSignedContent().getContent());
        System.out.println("Signed content: " + signedContent + "\n");

        String envelopedData = encoder.encode(sigData.getEncoded());
        System.out.println("Enveloped data: " + envelopedData);
```

AFTER COMMENTS FROM VOLKERK :

How I generate the signature+data file :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // String text = "This is a message";

        // File file = new
        // File("C:\\Users\\mayooranM\\Desktop\\SignatureVerificationTest\\ProcessExplorer.zip");
        // fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        // byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        Path filepath = Paths.get("G:\\IntelliJTestProjects\\googleplaces.zip");
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(filepath);

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_INSTANCE);
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());
        Key key = ks.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());

        // Sign
        PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey) key;
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA", "BC");
        signature.initSign(privKey);
        signature.update(fileContent);

        // Build CMS
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(KEYSTORE_ALIAS);
        List certList = new ArrayList();
        CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signature.sign());
        certList.add(cert);
        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(privKey);
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(
                new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build())
                        .build(sha1Signer, cert));
        gen.addCertificates(certs);
        CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, true);

        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();

        String signedContent = encoder.encode((byte[]) sigData.getSignedContent().getContent());
        System.out.println("Signed content: " + signedContent + "\n");

        String envelopedData = encoder.encode(sigData.getEncoded());
        System.out.println("Enveloped data: " + envelopedData);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                "G:\\IntelliJTestProjects\\SignedZip.zip");
        fos.write(envelopedData.getBytes());
        fos.close();

    }
```

How I verify data:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

            Path path = Paths
                    .get("G:\\IntelliJTestProjects\\SignedZip.zip");
            byte[] signedContent = Files.readAllBytes(path);

            String output = new String(signedContent);

            System.out.println("output: " + output);

            CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(Base64.decode(signedContent));
            Store store = cms.getCertificates();
            SignerInformationStore signers = cms.getSignerInfos();
            Collection c = signers.getSigners();
            Iterator it = c.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next();
                Collection certCollection = store.getMatches(signer.getSID());
                Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
                X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
                X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certHolder);
                if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert))) {
                    System.out.println("verified");
                }
            }

            CMSProcessable origData = cms.getSignedContent() ;
            byte[] originalContent  = (byte[]) origData.getContent();

             ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(originalContent));
                ZipEntry entry = null;
                while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {

                    String entryName = entry.getName();

                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(entryName);

                    byte[] byteBuff = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = zipStream.read(byteBuff)) != -1)
                    {
                        out.write(byteBuff, 0, bytesRead);
                    }

                    out.close();
                    zipStream.closeEntry();
                }
                zipStream.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `CMSSignedData cms = new CMSSignedData(cer.getSignature());` - what is that supposed to do?

Comment: What do you mean whats that supposed to do?

Comment: The documentation says `CMSSignedData(byte[] sigBlock)` but you're passing a certificate there.

Comment: I'm passing cer.getSignature. Its supposed to return the signature block right?

Comment: The signature block of what exactly? I'm no bouncy castle expert. But doesn't it strike you as odd that nowhere in your first code snippet the output of your second snippets appears? The data is _not_ added to the certificate; like when you draw up deeds the notary might use your passport to verify (in this case your identity) but he/she doesn't alter the passport.

Comment: I didn't forget you ;-) and since it looks like nobody else is taking on this question: Can you please elaborate a bit on what you're trying to achieve? (The code is _how_ you want to  achieve it; let's go one or two levels up) E.g. is the output format fixed? I asked because you're hashing+signing the content manually `Signature signature = .... signature.update(fileContent);` and then pass that result to the CMSSignedDataGenerator. Is that mandatory because you need the resulting asn1 in a (very) specific format?

Comment: Thanks for keeping in touch mate :) what I really wanted was to sign a zip file and then at another end verify its signature before extracting it. So I managed to alter this code and got the answer. But for verification, I need the .sig file as well. Is there another way to do it without keeping the .sig file? Like is it possible to put it somewhere in the certificate or embed into the zip file? This is the code I wrote http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870544/signature-not-verified-though-the-correct-public-key-and-signature-file-are-bein/35879267#35879267

Comment: The problem is that you need {data|signature} to verfiy that the data has been signed (and not altered). Now if you add something to the .zip you're changing the _data_ part. Take a look at the image at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#Structure . What is "missing" is another container around or next to the "file1...fileN,central", something were you can store additional data yet get the unaltered data container. Signed JARs e.g. are zip archives, that have a list of the files and a signature for that list ...as files insinde the archive. Would that be feasible?

Comment: Btw: Last time I checked the _tools_ for creating a signed jar weren't exactly "public". There is the jarsigner tool, but the code behind it doesn't seem to be supposed to be re-used. The other option (ok, one of the other options) is: You're using CMSSignedDataGenerator. It's description says: "general class for generating a pkcs7-signature message". And it _can_ contain the original message/data. The result wouldn't be a valid ZIP archive, but something from which you can _get_ the zip archive. Which route do you want to take? I'd suggest (if possible) the one described in this comment....

Comment: @VolkerK mate I edited the question with your suggestion. But the zipStream.getNextEntry() method is not returning anything though I can see a byte array in "originalContent" variable. :( Isn't this how we are supposed to re-generate the original data from the originalData+signed file?

Comment: Ok, let me fiddle with that code a while. Might take a while: It's been a while since I've done java coding and even longer for bouncy castle ;-)

Comment: Ah sure mate! thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Part 2

Ok, now that you've got a file containing the pkcs7 signed data, let's try to retrieve the contents and verify the integrity  ...and validity.
The goal is again not to load the whole thing into memory. Looks like [CMSSignedDataParser](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataParser.html) can do that.
Since the documentation says

> Note: that because we are in a streaming mode [...] it is important that the methods on the parser are called in the appropriate order.

So, let's first look at what we actual got so far. For that I used a text file containing the line `Mary had a little lamb` as the input file, instead of the .m4v (or the .zip in your case) and passed the result to http://lapo.it/asn1js/ (you got to love this tool....)

[image: The asn1-structure of the result]

So, the actual contents comes before the signature data and we have to read the entries in the order they appear in the file. Would be easier the other way round, but ...
The idea is to write the contents to the target file regardless of whether it checks out or not. If it doesn't just delete file. (Drawback: If it contains e.g. a virus a virus scanner might be triggered ...too bad. I leave handling that up to you.)

```
public class SignedDataTest {
  ... see Part 1

    private static void verify(Path signedFile, Path extractToFile) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(signedFile.toFile());

        DigestCalculatorProvider build = new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build();
        CMSSignedDataParser sp = new CMSSignedDataParser(build, fis);

        // we have to read the whole stream sp.getSignedContent().getContentStream()
        // just copy it to the target file
        Files.copy(sp.getSignedContent().getContentStream(), extractToFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        // now we can go on with the other stuff.....

        Store certStore = sp.getCertificates();
        // the examples create a new instance of this for each certificate. 
        // I don't think that's necessary, but you might want to look into that...
        JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder verifier = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC");

        for (Object objSigner : sp.getSignerInfos().getSigners()) {
            SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) objSigner;
            // as I understand it, there should be only one match ....but anyways....
            for (Object objMatch : certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID())) {
                X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) objMatch;
                System.out.print("verifying against " + certHolder.getSubject().toString());
                if (signer.verify(verifier.build(certHolder))) {
                    System.out.println(": verified");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(": no match");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, what does this actually do/test for? It fetches the signer info from the pkcs7 signedData and then checks the hash and the signature againt the certificates that are *contained in* the signedData. Not good enough, I and any other attacker can put *any* certificate in there; so I create a new KeyPiar generate a selfsigned certificate for that key pair and put just any zip file in there I like, preferably a nasty phishing tool.
That's most likely the reason why you've used `KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI")` in your code; a KeyStore which you implictly trust. So, let's do just that.
Instead of building the SignerInformationVerifier from the data in the signedData file, we pass a ready-made verfier to the method. And this verifier is primed with the certificate from the windows "KeyStore". Btw: you cannot mix the BC and the SunMSCAPI providers arbitrarily; but you can mix them this way, i.e. have BC check the data integrity and SunMSCAPI check whether the hash has been signed by something considered trustworthy.

(sorry, got to go. I'll post just the complete sample class; there's a lot to say about it though ....actually one could write books about that ...actually actually books *have* been written about that topic ;-) )

```
public class SignedDataTest {

    private static final File KEYSTORE_FILE = new File("c:\\temp\\Software_View_Certificate_Authority.p12");
    private static final String KEYSTORE_TYPE = "pkcs12";
    private static final char[] KEYSTORE_PWD = "foobar".toCharArray();
    private static final String KEYSTORE_ALIAS = "Software View Certificate Authority";

    private static final Path CONTENT_SRC_PATH = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\test.txt");
    private static final Path CONTENT_TARGET_PATH = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\test-retrieved.txt");
    private static final Path SIGNEDDATA_TARGET_PATH = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\test.txt.signed.pkcs7");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        doForth();
        andBack();
    }

    private static void doForth() throws Exception {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE, "BC");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PWD);
        X500PrivateCredential creds = new X500PrivateCredential(
                (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(KEYSTORE_ALIAS),
                (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, KEYSTORE_PWD)
        );
        createSignature(CONTENT_SRC_PATH, creds, new FileOutputStream(SIGNEDDATA_TARGET_PATH.toFile()));
    }

    private static void andBack() throws Exception {
        KeyStore msCertStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
        msCertStore.load(null, null);
        SignerInformationVerifier verifier = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("SunMSCAPI")
                .build(((X509Certificate) msCertStore.getCertificate("Software View Certificate Authority")));
        verify(SIGNEDDATA_TARGET_PATH, CONTENT_TARGET_PATH, verifier);
    }

    private static void verify(Path signedFile, Path extractToFile, SignerInformationVerifier verifier) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(signedFile.toFile());

        DigestCalculatorProvider build = new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build();
        CMSSignedDataParser sp = new CMSSignedDataParser(build, fis);

        // we have to read the whole stream sp.getSignedContent().getContentStream()
        // just copy it to the target file
        Files.copy(sp.getSignedContent().getContentStream(), extractToFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        // now we can go on with the other stuff.....

        Store certStore = sp.getCertificates();
        // the examples create a new instance of this for each certificate. 
        // I don't think that's necessary, but you might want to look into that...

        for (Object objSigner : sp.getSignerInfos().getSigners()) {
            SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) objSigner;
            if (signer.verify(verifier)) {
                System.out.println("verified");
                // now(!) you want to keep the target content file
            } else {
                // actually a "org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignerDigestMismatchException: message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value"
                // exception will be thrown in case the contents has been altered
                // So, you will need a try-catch(-finally?) construct to delete the target contents file in such cases....
                System.out.println("no match");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createSignature(Path srcfile, X500PrivateCredential creds, FileOutputStream target) throws Exception {
        CMSSignedDataStreamGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataStreamGenerator() {
            {
                addSignerInfoGenerator(
                        new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                                new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()
                        ).build(
                                new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(creds.getPrivateKey()),
                                creds.getCertificate()
                        )
                );
                addCertificates(new JcaCertStore(new ArrayList<X509Certificate>() {
                    {
                        add(creds.getCertificate());
                    }
                }));
            }
        };
        try (OutputStream sigOut = gen.open(target, true)) {
            Files.copy(srcfile, sigOut);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot mate! I will try this today and let you know the result :)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted man! Not even the Java security books or bouncy castle wiki had this much explanation. Thanks a lot bro! :) And thank you very much for taking your time with this :(

Comment: Hey also could you suggest me some good books to be read on Java security? I read Java Security from O'Reilly media, apart from that anything? :)

Comment: tentative suggestion: `Cryptography Decrypted` by H. X. Mel and Doris M. Baker , `Beginning Cryptography with Java` by David Hook. But there are so many and some parts of bouncy castle are in flux. E.g. I wanted to create the certificate used in the example via bouncy castle and thought "WTF, where's the X509V3CerificateGenerator  ...again. But hey, there's a PBKDF2WithHmacSHA factory now". (Now you can look up since when I didn't use bc, or at least these parts ;-)) Keep an eye on which version it targets. Bonus points when the book describes "authenticated encryption" e.g. aes-gcm.

Comment: Thanks a ton mate! I will look into those books! :)

Comment: @VolkerK, I have serious problem with cMSTypedData.getContent() to reverse actual plainText data when signing other than english text (Windows Capicom Returning excepted output). plainText data like (સારું) -> signing using org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64.encode(cmsSignedData.getEncoded()) and then again verify actual data (plainData = new String((byte[])cMSTypedData.getContent());) which is returning junk character like (¸¾°Á). i run your code which is also returning junk character plainText. please guide. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Janak Dhanani: might be a charset-related problem. I assume there's a plainData-string on the "sending"-side as well and you use something like plainData.getBytes()? In that case make sure that the encoding matches on both sides. In the simplest case use `plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` on the sending side and `new String((byte[])cMSTypedData.getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`on the receiving side.

Comment: @VolkerK, Bravo you saved my time and issue resolved. as expected windows capicom using UTF-16LE while java has StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE which need to be done on both side of byte to string and visa-versa.

Answer (score 4):

### Part 1

Let's start with some transformations of the code. (I wonder how long an answer can be....)
Step 1: Not much going on here; just setting up the "framework" - and as you can see: yes, I'm really running/testing the code ;-)

```
public class SignedDataTest {
    private static final File KEYSTORE_FILE = new File("c:\\temp\\Software_View_Certificate_Authority.p12");
    private static final String KEYSTORE_TYPE = "pkcs12";
    private static final char[] KEYSTORE_PWD = "foobar".toCharArray();
    private static final String KEYSTORE_ALIAS = "Software View Certificate Authority";

    private static final Path CONTENT_SRC_PATH = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\Londo Buttons are melting.m4v");
    private static final Path CONTENT_TARGET_PATH = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\Londo Buttons are melting-retrieved.m4v");
    private static final Path SIGNEDDATA_TARGET_PATH = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\Londo Buttons are melting-retrieved.m4v.signed.pkcs7");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        createSignature();
    }

    private static void createSignature() throws Exception {
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(CONTENT_SRC_PATH);

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE, "BC");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PWD);
        Key key = ks.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, KEYSTORE_PWD);

        // Sign
        PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey)key;
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA", "BC");
        signature.initSign(privKey);
        signature.update(fileContent);

        // Build CMS
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(KEYSTORE_ALIAS);
        List certList = new ArrayList();
        CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signature.sign());
        certList.add(cert);
        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(privKey);
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(
                new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build())
                .build(sha1Signer, cert));
        gen.addCertificates(certs);
        CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, true);

        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        String signedContent = encoder.encode((byte[]) sigData.getSignedContent().getContent());
        System.out.println("Signed content: " + signedContent + "\n");

        String envelopedData = encoder.encode(sigData.getEncoded());
        System.out.println("Enveloped data: " + envelopedData);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(SIGNEDDATA_TARGET_PATH.toString());
        fos.write(envelopedData.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Step 2: This is probably the hardest; the transformation that makes the code look unlike *your* code the most. Take your time to understand what I'm doing here. I want to get rid of some of the unecessary stuff (e.g. the Base64 encoder) and get a bit more condensed code. This makes debugging a bit harder, since I removed most of the temporary variables, "hiding" them in the initializer block - doh, what's the proper name of that feature?)

```
public class SignedDataTest {

    private static final File KEYSTORE_FILE = new File("c:\\temp\\Software_View_Certificate_Authority.p12");
    private static final String KEYSTORE_TYPE = "pkcs12";
    private static final char[] KEYSTORE_PWD = "foobar".toCharArray();
    private static final String KEYSTORE_ALIAS = "Software View Certificate Authority";

    private static final Path CONTENT_SRC_PATH = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\Londo Buttons are melting.m4v");
    private static final Path CONTENT_TARGET_PATH = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\Londo Buttons are melting-retrieved.m4v");
    private static final Path SIGNEDDATA_TARGET_PATH = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\Londo Buttons are melting-retrieved.m4v.signed.pkcs7");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        doForth();
        // doBack();
    }

    private static void doForth() throws Exception {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE, "BC");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PWD);
        X500PrivateCredential creds = new X500PrivateCredential(
                (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(KEYSTORE_ALIAS),
                (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, KEYSTORE_PWD)
        );
        createSignature(CONTENT_SRC_PATH, creds, new FileOutputStream(SIGNEDDATA_TARGET_PATH.toFile()));
    }

    private static void createSignature(Path srcfile, X500PrivateCredential creds, FileOutputStream target) throws Exception {
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(CONTENT_SRC_PATH);
        // Sign
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA", "BC");
        signature.initSign(creds.getPrivateKey());
        signature.update(fileContent);

        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator() {
            {
                addSignerInfoGenerator(
                        new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                                new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()
                        ).build(
                                new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(creds.getPrivateKey()),
                                creds.getCertificate()
                        )
                );
                addCertificates(new JcaCertStore(new ArrayList<X509Certificate>() {
                    {
                        add(creds.getCertificate());
                    }
                }));
            }
        };
        // Build CMS
        CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signature.sign());
        CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, true);
        // write raw data instead of base64
        target.write(sigData.getEncoded());
    }
}
```

Step 3: This is probably the most important step: It changes the code from "cannot work as intended on a fundamental level" to "in principle this might work". You're creating a signature manually and then pass that signature to the CMSSignedDataGenerator as the message. In effect you're creating a signature of a signature; the "real" contents is lost. What you actually want to do is create a signature of the (file) contents:

```
private static void createSignature(Path srcfile, X500PrivateCredential creds, FileOutputStream target) throws Exception {
    byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(CONTENT_SRC_PATH);

    CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator() {
            ...
    };
    // Build CMS
    CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(fileContent);
    CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, true);
    // write raw data instead of base64
    target.write(sigData.getEncoded());
}
```

Step 4: You read the complete contents into memory. That might not be a good idea for a large input file.

```
private static void createSignature(Path srcfile, X500PrivateCredential creds, FileOutputStream target) throws Exception {                
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator() {
        ...
        };
        // see https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSProcessableFile.html
        CMSProcessableFile msg = new CMSProcessableFile(srcfile.toFile());
        CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, true);
        // write raw data instead of base64
        target.write(sigData.getEncoded());
    }
```

Step 5: Again memory usage: `gen.generate(msg, true)`: The `true` parameter means that the complete msg is included in the asn1-structure. When you call `.getEncoded()` you get a byte array of the complete asn1-structure, i.e. you have the complete file in memory again. RAM is cheap, but let's try to avoid that anyway. There's another generator called [CMSSignedDataStreamGenerator](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataStreamGenerator.html) which seems to offer what we need. Instead of working on byte arrays, you give it an OutputStream it can write the result to, and you get OutputStream you can write the contents to:

```
private static void createSignature(Path srcfile, X500PrivateCredential creds, FileOutputStream target) throws Exception {                
    CMSSignedDataStreamGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataStreamGenerator() {
        {
            addSignerInfoGenerator(
                    new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                            new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()
                    ).build(
                            new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(creds.getPrivateKey()),
                            creds.getCertificate()
                    )
            );
            addCertificates(new JcaCertStore(new ArrayList<X509Certificate>() {
                {
                    add(creds.getCertificate());
                }
            }));
        }
    };
    try (OutputStream sigOut = gen.open(target, true)) {
        Files.copy(srcfile, sigOut);
    }
}
```

So much for creating the signed message. I will post the verify-part in another answer - but have to work for real/for a living for a while.....

edit: There's probably still room to post the complete/final sample class

```
public class SignedDataTest {

    private static final File KEYSTORE_FILE = new File("c:\\temp\\Software_View_Certificate_Authority.p12");
    private static final String KEYSTORE_TYPE = "pkcs12";
    private static final char[] KEYSTORE_PWD = "foobar".toCharArray();
    private static final String KEYSTORE_ALIAS = "Software View Certificate Authority";

    private static final Path CONTENT_SRC_PATH = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\Londo Buttons are melting.m4v");
    private static final Path CONTENT_TARGET_PATH = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\Londo Buttons are melting-retrieved.m4v");
    private static final Path SIGNEDDATA_TARGET_PATH = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\Londo Buttons are melting-retrieved.m4v.signed.pkcs7");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        doForth();
        //doBack();
    }

    private static void doForth() throws Exception {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE, "BC");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PWD);
        X500PrivateCredential creds = new X500PrivateCredential(
                (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(KEYSTORE_ALIAS),
                (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, KEYSTORE_PWD)
        );
        createSignature(CONTENT_SRC_PATH, creds, new FileOutputStream(SIGNEDDATA_TARGET_PATH.toFile()));
    }

    private static void createSignature(Path srcfile, X500PrivateCredential creds, FileOutputStream target) throws Exception {                
        CMSSignedDataStreamGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataStreamGenerator() {
            {
                addSignerInfoGenerator(
                        new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                                new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()
                        ).build(
                                new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(creds.getPrivateKey()),
                                creds.getCertificate()
                        )
                );
                addCertificates(new JcaCertStore(new ArrayList<X509Certificate>() {
                    {
                        add(creds.getCertificate());
                    }
                }));
            }
        };
        try (OutputStream sigOut = gen.open(target, true)) {
            Files.copy(srcfile, sigOut);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a bit confused, how you obtain signedData from a p7s file?
When I want to do this, I get `malformed content` exception